# Trying to Convert VB.Net to C# ViewState Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net

**VB.NET Code**

```
If ViewState("lstSetting") IsNot Nothing Then
  username = ViewState("lstSetting")("Email")
  password = ViewState("lstSetting")("Psw")
  mHost = ViewState("lstSetting")("Host").ToString.Split(":")(1)
  mPort = ViewState("lstSetting")("Port").ToString.Split(":")(1)
End If
password = Trim(dec(ondecrypt(Trim(password))))
```

**C# Code**

```
if (ViewState["lstSetting"] != null)
{
  username = ViewState["lstSetting"]("Email");
  password = ViewState["lstSetting"]("Psw");
  mHost = ViewState["lstSetting"]("Host");
  //.ToString.Split(":")(1)
  mPort = ViewState["lstSetting"]("Port");
  //.ToString.Split(":")(1)
}
password=Strings.Trim(ModCommon.dec(ModCommon.ondecrypt(Strings.Trim(password))));`
```

> **Error:** Method Name Expected...

Error is Displayed Here

> `ViewState["lstSetting"]("Email")`

Comment: What type of object is stored in `lstSetting`?

Comment: ViewState["lstSetting"]("Email") doesn't make sence in c#

Comment: I had ReEdit Question..

Comment: First, you are trying to access a dictionary using `()`, unless you store Func<string,string>() objects in `lstSetting`. Second, ViewState is a dynamic type, so you could have written `ViewState.lstSetting.Email` both in C# and VB.NET

Comment: What is the type of `lstSetting`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you point to the `dynamic` variant? At least it isn't [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.item(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it is :  Dictionary<string, string> lstSetting = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: @PatrickHofman oops, confused it with ViewBag/ViewData. So happy I've started to forget about Web Forms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ViewState["lstSetting"]("Email")
```

should be

```
((Dictionary<string, string>)ViewState["lstSetting"])["Email"]
```

Actually, you should retrieve `ViewState["lstSetting"]` *once* and then use it. But that goes for both code snippets.

Comment: Won't work since [`ViewState.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.item(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `object`.

Comment: Since VB.NET isn't that type safe.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok, fixed it... another reason why I never trusted any of the VBs :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `lstSetting` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you need to do cast the variable first, then get the variable using the `Item` accessor `[]`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = ViewState["lstSetting"] as Dictionary<string, string>;

if (dic != null)
{
    username = dic["Email"];

    // etc
}
```